# OCSP over SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, ocsp, confidentiality

As far as I know, OCSP only provides explicit means for requests and responses to be signed ([RFC2560, page 7] for requests, and [RFC2560, page 8] for responses), but it does not make any mention about encryption. Is it typical (or even possible, which I suppose that of course it is) to run OCSP over SSL/TLS to also guarantee its confidentiality?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? Certificates are public documents. What's the risk?

Comment: I'm just thinking of a [probably] atypical scenario. E.g. I own a company for which I run a private CA, and I don't want any rival company to know which users I am revoking: a revoked user means that he/she is a [probably] fired employee, and they would [probably] be able to bribe him/her in order to gain private information. Or the example that erickson gave below, which seems much more typical.

Comment: If you'd think more from a Integrity instead of confidentiality.  I think it would be possible to perform MiTM attack, giving an incorrect status about a certificate revocation status, forcing a user to use it's old -compromised- certificate.

Comment: This recent news helped me to surface this old question. The Apple OCSP check is a valid use case to use TLS. It would allow man in the middle or my ISP to spy on the apps I am using and when. https://blog.jacopo.io/en/post/apple-ocsp/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using SSL/TLS. But consider this:

> When certificates include a cRLDistributionPoints extension with an
>      https URI or similar scheme, circular dependencies can be introduced.
>      The relying party is forced to perform an additional path validation
>      in order to obtain the CRL required to complete the initial path
>      validation!  Circular conditions can also be created with an https
>      URI (or similar scheme) in the authorityInfoAccess or
>      subjectInfoAccess extensions.  At worst, this situation can create
>      unresolvable dependencies.

Taken from RFC5280, Section 8. This section addresses the problem using https for CRL distribution points. But you will have the same issue using SSL/TLS for OCSP requests: you have to check the validity of the server certificate...

Answer (score 3):

In the appendix of the RFC2560 is the following written:

> A.1.1 Request 
>   [...] Where privacy is
>      a requirement, OCSP transactions exchanged using HTTP MAY be
>      protected using either TLS/SSL or some other lower layer protocol.

But the most OCSP-Responder only provide HTTP without TLS/SSL.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely possible, but it's not typical. If you are requesting the status of a host certificate, the OCSP request is unlikely to reveal anything an eavesdropper doesn't already know—namely, the host that you are trying to authenticate.

For S/MIME email or other applications, OCSP requests could be a lot more sensitive, because they would support organizational analysis. Using HTTPS transport could be be a good idea there.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But then, since it is quite possible to run OCSP over SSL/TLS, why is encryption not explicitly supported, but signing is? Wouldn't it have been easier to just move all that burden to SSL/TLS (or IPSEC or any other security protocol)?

Comment: @Ginswich I think the signatures are there so that responses can be created in advance, or cached by the client. In other words, the signatures protect integrity at rest. I know some commercial OCSP responders offer, for better performance, pre-computation of responses when they process a CRL. These server tend to respond with a chunk of responses, one of which corresponds to the request you made.

Comment: Makes much sense. Thank you again.